# NullPointerException in variable initiating

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this code:

```
public class loops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        person[] people = new person[5];
        int i = 0;
//        for (person p : people) {
//            p.age = i++;
//        }
        for (int j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
            people[i].age = i++;
        }

        for (person p : people) {
            System.out.print(p.age);
        }
    }
}

class person {

    public int age;
}
```

I tried both loops but the result was null pointer exception forever.

Why?

The exception line is these:

```
            people[i].age = i++;
```

and

```
            p.age = i++;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just created an array of `person`, you haven't instantiated any of the items, they are all pointing to `null` , you need to do:

```
people[i] = new person();
```

in your loop.

So your loop would be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
            people[i] = new person();
            people[i].age = i++;
        }
```

Comment: Ok, How initialize each `person` item in `for (person p : people)` loop?

Comment: @Sunrise, you shouldn't do that. If you fix the code before that you will not get the exception in foreach.

Comment: @Sunrise, if you are expecting `null` in your `for(person p: people)` then check `if (p != null)` before displaying records.

Answer (score 2):

Though you did not explicitly tell us where, I am guessing the program is crashing at this line in your first `for` loop:

```
people[i].age = i++;
```

Remember that merely because you did this:

```
person[] people = new person[5];
```

Doesn't mean you have an array of `person` objects. It merely creates an array that can contain `person` objects, but you **still need to create those objects**.

**Edit**

Please remember the Java naming convention for classes; they should begin with an upper case letter (so `public class Loops` and `class Person`). Otherwise, it can become difficult at times to know whether a method is being invoked on a class, or an instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually instantiate a new object in each position of the array before using it, by default all positions in an object array are `null` unless explicitly initialized:

```
people[0] = new person();
people[1] = new person();
// and so on
```

Even simpler, use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
    people[i] = new person();
```

We can use the same loop to initialize the people and their age in a single step, and we can use the same index, too - there's no need to have both `i` and `j`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    people[i] = new person();
    people[i].age = i;
}
```

Also notice that by convention your `person` class should be called `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
new person[5]
```

does not instantiate 5 objects of type `person` but only an array with 5 placeholder for objects of type `person`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized people.

```
person[] people = new person[5];
```

makes all pointing to null.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized an array of people, but not any people.

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   People p = new People();
   p.age = 4;
   people[i] = p;
}
```